# iOS Change badge color inside UIMoreNavigationController in UITabBarController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I customize the background color and its tint color with this code:

```
var blackBGColor = new UIColor(new nfloat(40) / 255f,
                               new nfloat(40) / 255f,
                               new nfloat(40) / 255f, 1f);

this.MoreNavigationController.TopViewController.View.BackgroundColor = blackBGColor;

var moreTableView = (UITableView)this.MoreNavigationController.TopViewController.View;
moreTableView.TintColor = UIColor.White;
foreach (var cell in moreTableView.VisibleCells)
{
     cell.BackgroundColor = blackBGColor;
     cell.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
     var selectedView = new UIView
     {
          BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray
     };
     cell.SelectedBackgroundView = selectedView;
}

this.MoreNavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
this.MoreNavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
this.MoreNavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
this.MoreNavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = new UIColor(24f / 255f, 24f / 255f, 24f / 255f, 1f);
```

But I couldn't change the badge color inside `UIMoreNavigationController`.

I've tried this:

```
this.MoreNavigationController.TopViewController.TabBarItem.BadgeColor = UIColor.White
```

but it's not working.

Tried this one too inside `WillShowViewController`:

`this.ViewControllers[4].TabBarItem.BadgeColor = UIColor.White`

but still not working.

Is there any way to change the badge color?

[image: More navigation controller]

---

**UPDATE:**

After investigating the hierarchy of `MoreNavigationController`, apparently the badge value for `Priority` and `DueBy` tab is assign to a `UILabel` inside `_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue`. The hierarchy is:

- `this.MoreNavigationController.ViewControllers[0]`: this is a `UIMoreListController`

  - Get the `View` and cast it to `UITableView` because that `View` is a `_UIMoreListTableView`

    - Then iterate inside that tableview `VisibleCells`, check the `IEnumerator` and in the forth object there is `_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue`

      - The `SubViews[0]` inside `_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue` is a `UILabel` and the label's text is the badge value.

Based on that, I change the label `TextColor` and `BackgroundColor` in `WillShowViewController`. It works but I need to go back and forth from `Priority/DueBy` tab to `More` tab. It never works on the first time.

```
[Export("navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:")]
public void WillShowViewController(UINavigationController navigationController, UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
{
     if (this.MoreNavigationController.ViewControllers.Contains(viewController))
     {
          this.ViewControllers[4].TabBarItem.BadgeValue = this.ViewModel.SelectedPrioritiesFilter.Count > 0 ? this.ViewModel.SelectedPrioritiesFilter.Count.ToString() : null;
          this.ViewControllers[5].TabBarItem.BadgeValue = this.ViewModel.SelectedDueByFilter != null ? "1" : null;

          //this is the code to change the color
          var vc = this.MoreNavigationController.ViewControllers[0];
          var moreTableView = (UITableView)vc.View;
          foreach (var cell in moreTableView.VisibleCells)
          {
               var enumerator = cell.GetEnumerator();
               var i = 0;
               while (enumerator.MoveNext())
               {
                    //_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue is in the forth object
                    if(i == 3) 
                    {
                        //_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue is a UIView
                        if (enumerator.Current is UIView)
                        {
                             var current = (UIView)enumerator.Current;
                             if (current != null)
                             {
                                 if (current.Subviews.Length > 0)
                                 {
                                      var label = (UILabel)current.Subviews[0];
                                      label.TextColor = UIColor.White;
                                      label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                                 }
                             }
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: 1. I searched source code  in TabbedRenderer but didn't find anything.  2. I use `Debug View Hierarchy` with Xcode to find badge view inside moreNavigationContoller ,it is called `_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue` , but unfortunately we cannot be able to access it .So  I think the only way is to customize the tableview or tableviewCell instead of the original one.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT I've tried to change the color in `_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue` in `WillShowViewController`. But, it only works after I go back and forth (at least need 2-3 times) from more tab to priority/due by tab. It never works for the first time.

Comment: Could  you attach the code to help us reproduce？

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT I've added the code

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue and figured the reason out.

It is because the TableView has not finished rendering(drawing) when you retrieve the view hierarchy in `WillShowViewController`.

#### My test

**View Hierarchy in `WillShowViewController`**

```
UITableViewCellContentView
UIButton
```

**View Hierarchy in `DidShowViewController`**

```
UITableViewCellContentView
UIButton
_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue
_UITableViewCellSeparatorView
UITableViewCellContentView
UIButton
_UITableViewCellSeparatorView
```

So you just need replace the `WillShowViewController` with `DidShowViewController`.

#### PS: Small Suggestion

To avoid the change of View Hierarchy by Apple,  you can use the condition like `if (view.Class.Name.ToString() == "_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue")` instead of judging which level  the `_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue` is.

Comment: if I put the code in `DidShowViewController`, it will show the badge value in gray and white background color then in several seconds, it changes to white and clear bg color.

Comment: @currarpickt yes, this is a problem, but it is better than pushing to next viewController and back...

Comment: haven't solve it. even if I put the code in `DidShowViewController`, sometimes it doesn't work (and this is random, can't predict it). I need to go back and forth again between the controllers if that's happen.

Comment: So what are folks doing to fix this? I have a similar issue with a dark background I'm trying to solve for.